# External javascript not working - local file

Tags: javascript

I am using a local HTML file with link to an external script (located in the same directory) that worked when in the file, but externally doesn't.  Neither Firefox nor Chrome.  Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="docket.js"> </script>
</head>
<body onload="doFunction()"> ...
```

The script is in a .js file, which has (simplified):

```
function doFunction() ....
```

Comment: Does your docket.js files actually contain the opening and closing `<script>` tags? It shouldn't

Comment: Also, to help you debugging, you should read the browser console (F12 -> Console), you probably have an error showing up there.

Comment: It did, I've tried it both ways.  Removed them. - still doesn't work.

Comment: try adding `window.addEventListener('load', doFunction);` in your `js` file and remove `onload="dofunction()"` from your `html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, you shouldn't include the script tags in your external js file.

Also try to move the script line at the bottom before the closing body tag.

If after removing, it still doesn't work, you should open the developer tools to get clue of what is going on.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body onload="doFunction()">
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="docket.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

docket.js:

```
function doFunction() {
    alert("hello...");
}
```

Note: no script tags

Comment: OP claims they tried it both ways and it didn't make a difference

Comment: Yes - removed them in the file (and above too)

Comment: See below - my bad.  Thanks, though.  The no scripts thing helped.

Comment: @thf No problem, it is also good practice to put the script at the bottom before the closing body tag.

Answer (score 0):

As per w3school - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp

> The external script file cannot contain the  tag.

The syntax for script tag is -

`<script src="URL">`

Where your URL is -
1. An absolute URL - points to another web site (like src="http://www.example.com/example.js") OR
2. A relative URL - points to a file within a web site (like src="/scripts/example.js")

> Note: with HTML5, `type` attribute for script tag is optional.

I'd suggest to add a `noscript` tag just to make sure you have JS enabled in your browser.

`<noscript>Your browser does not support JavaScript!</noscript>`